# Haskell type magical world of Oz filtering nicta course functors and applicatives

Tags: haskell

Taken from the [NICTA course](https://github.com/NICTA/course/blob/master/src/Course/Applicative.hs#L159):

```
-- | Filter a list with a predicate that produces an effect.
--
-- >>> filtering (Id . even) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. Nil)
-- Id [4,6]
--
-- >>> filtering (\a -> if a > 13 then Empty else Full (a <= 7)) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. Nil)
-- Full [4,5,6]
--
-- >>> filtering (\a -> if a > 13 then Empty else Full (a <= 7)) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. 7 :. 8 :. 9 :. Nil)
-- Full [4,5,6,7]
--
-- >>> filtering (\a -> if a > 13 then Empty else Full (a <= 7)) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. 13 :. 14 :. Nil)
-- Empty
--
-- >>> filtering (>) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. 7 :. 8 :. 9 :. 10 :. 11 :. 12 :. Nil) 8
-- [9,10,11,12]
--
-- >>> filtering (const $ True :. True :.  Nil) (1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil)
-- [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
--
filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
```

I don't understand the signature of this function.

"It takes a function `(a -> f Bool)` and a `List a` and returns a `f (List a)`"

First example:

```
-- >>> filtering (Id . even) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. Nil)
-- :type (. even)
-- (Bool -> c) -> a -> c
```

Given:
`data Id a = Id a`

How does this happen:

```
-- :type (Id . even)
-- a -> Id Bool
```

This one I understand:

```
-- >>> filtering (\a -> if a > 13 then Empty else Full (a <= 7)) (4 :. 5 :. Nil)
```

What about these two:

```
-- >>> filtering (>) (4 :. 5 :. Nil) 8
-- >>> filtering (const $ True :. True :. Nil) (1 :. 2 :. Nil)
```

### Edit:

```
-- :type Id
-- a -> Id a

-- :type filtering
-- (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)

-- :type filtering Id
-- List Bool -> Id (List Bool)

-- Functor f is Id
-- (a -> f Bool) is replaced by (Bool -> Id Bool)
```

Similarly:

```
-- :type (<)
-- a -> a -> Bool

-- :type filtering
-- (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)

-- :type filtering (<)
-- List a -> a -> List a

-- Functor f is (-> a)
-- (a -> f Bool) is replaced by (a -> a -> Bool)
```

I think like this.

Other problems:

```
-- :type Id
-- a -> Id a
-- :type (. even)
-- (Bool -> c) -> a -> c
-- :type (Id . even)
-- a -> Id Bool
```

I don't understand the final transformation.

Give answer by aweinstock:

`(Id :: a -> Id a)` is put in the position of `(Bool -> c)` in
             `((. even) :: (Bool -> c) -> a -> c)`, so "a" unifies with "Bool",
             and therefore "c" unifies with "Id Bool"

Comment: Haskell functions are [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), so they don't take two arguments...

Comment: explain more please with an answer @MrTsjolder

Comment: Why are you commenting every single line of code? do you realize that i this way you are effectively turning off the syntax highlighting? If you want to do so simple put `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` at the beginning of the post.

Comment: I don't know I never write haskell code @Bakuriu It is supposed to be ghci output so.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, consider the instances of `Applicative` you have at hand:

> ```
> instance Applicative Id where
>
> instance Applicative List where
>
> instance Applicative Optional where
>
> instance Applicative ((->) t) where
> ```

Now, `filtering` has the following type

```
filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
```

We focus on `filtering (>)`. `(>)` has type `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`. This immediately fixes the instance of `Applicative`: it's `((->) t)`:

```
filtering (>) :: Ord a => List a -> ((-> a) List a)
-- or, written in the usual `a ->` style:
filtering (>) :: Ord a => List a -> (a -> List a)
```

Therefore, `filtering (>)` takes a `List a` and returns a function that expects a single value and ultimately returns a list:

```
filtering                       :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
filtering (>)                   :: Ord a =>                          List a -> (a  -> List a)
filtering (>) (4 :. 5 :. Nil)   ::                                             Int -> List Int
filtering (>) (4 :. 5 :. Nil) 8 ::                                                    List Int
```

By the way, you can check the types easily if you use GHCi and give `filtering` a type but no (valid) implementation:

```
ghci> let filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> [a] -> f [a]; filtering = undefined
ghci> :t filtering (>)
filtering (>) :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> [a]
```

Comment: @eguneys Neither your edit, nor your original post actually contain a _question_. Due to your edit, it's slowly getting unclear what you're actually asking about. That being said, have a look at the type of `(Id .)` instead of `(. even)`.